# Создание «активности» со списком избранного

Tags: java, android, listview

Как создать «избранное»?

Например, есть listview со статьями.

Как создать отдельное активити со списком добавленных?

Comment: Это можно сделать в том же активити, просто подставить в адаптер другие значения или вообще подставить в listview другой адаптер, если нужно менять поведение например. Для этого надо уметь получать список избранного, где-то хранить позиции или ID

Answer (score 1):

Если вы храните статьи в базе данных, то можно добавить в таблицу колонку "избранное", далее обновлять все поля в базе данных при добавлении элемента списка в избранное, а в другом Activity можете просто достать все элементы из базы, у которых флаг "избранное" активен (равен 1 или т.п. как сами логику зададите). И чтобы не доставать все элементы, а потом их проверять, можно составить нужный запросс в базу, в котором укажите, что нужно достать только те, у которых колонка "избранное" активно и плов готов!

Comment: тоже хотел написать такой же ответ, опередили вы меня :)

Comment: Кто успел, тот и съел)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы собираетесь хранить статьи локально, то, например, можно сохранять их в локальную базу и в другом активити подгружать уже из нее.